# After import, oEmbeds non-functional until manual republish

Tags: media, import, oembed

I've just finished cleaning up the data from an application I was using previously and have got everything into a few WXR files. As a final test, I just imported them back into a local test installation, and all Vimeo and YouTube oEmbeds are failing. (This presumably applies to any other oEmbed media; it just so happens those are the majority in this case) All that gets displayed is the video URLs as plain text.

The only way I've found to force the embeds to become functional is to manually republish the various posts, and it must be done via the full post edit screen. Quick Edit'ing and bulk editing on the listing screen has no effect. There are ~2000 of these posts, so this process is completely out of the question.

Is this a known problem? And, obviously, is there a way around it?
I can't find anything that matches this situation so far. Most support threads that seem close have to do with the import process stripping iframe/object embeds, not disabling oEmbeds. Others involve the oEmbed URLs not being recognized at all(read: the feature failing altogether), not in this specific context.

Alternately, what is the difference between publishing a post via quick/bulk editing and doing it on the full edit screen? (*Why* is there a difference?) And can that be hacked into the other process so I could at least do it that way?

[edit]
Just confirmed the behavior on the live installation.
I don't expect there'll be anything interesting, but for reference [a snippet](http://pastebin.com/Q2TCkqSX) of a couple of posts from one of the WXR files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can apply some [content filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) to ensure oEmbed will work. I applyed a [simple regex](https://github.com/vmassuchetto/wordpress-monospace2/blob/master/functions.php#L37) in one of my themes because I know of some plugins that can break the oEmbed support. This can also work for you.